# Date distinct count over week

Tags: sql, datetime, count, aggregate-functions, presto

Im trying to get a distinct count of user ids logs per day with every week as a partition for the distinct identification.
e.g. if one user logs on Friday/Saturday of week 1, and on Monday/Friday of week 2, i want to have a column that counts 1 in Friday and 0 in Saturday week 1, and 1 in Monday and 0 in Friday week 2.

If i have the following data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/COf69.png]

I expect this result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTRdu.png]

Im working with Presto, and have tried with dense_rank() solutions but with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select date, iso_week, sum(case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by userid, iso_week order by date) min_date
    from mytable t
) t
group by date, iso_week
```

Better yet, using the standard [`where` clause to aggregate functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation), which Presto supports:

```
select date, iso_week, count(*) filter(where rn = 1) cnt
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by userid, iso_week order by date) min_date
    from mytable t
) t
group by date, iso_week
```

Comment: Yes! that is exactly what i needed, thank you very much

Comment: Note that Presto supports filtered aggregations (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation), so you can do this: `count(*) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) AS cnt`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: thank for the information, I was not aware indeed. +1 for Presto!